# MySQL Count If using 4 tables or Perl

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a relatively convoluted query that relies on 4 different tables, unfortunately I do not have control of this data, but I do have to query it.

I ran this simpler query and it works using just table 1 and table 2

```
SELECT actor, receiver, count(IF(t2.group1 = "anxiety behavior", 1,0)) AS 'anxiety'
FROM ethogram_edited_obs_behaviors t1
JOIN ethogram_behaviors            t2 on t1.behavior = t2.behavior_code
GROUP BY actor;
```

Below are the 4 tables I need and the query I tried that didn't work

```
Table 1           |   Table 2                     | Table 3         |  Table 4           
Actor | Behavior  |   Behavior | type of Behavior |  subject | sex  |  subject |subject_code
 er     frown     |   frown    anxiety behavior   |  Eric       M   |  Eric    |    er
```

Here is the query that is failing

```
SELECT actor, count(IF(t2.group1 = "anxiety behavior", 1,0) AND(t3.sex = "M", 1,0)) AS 'anxiety',
FROM ethogram_edited_obs_behaviors t1
JOIN ethogram_behaviors            t2 on t1.behavior = t2.behavior_code
JOIN subject_code                  t3 on t1.actor    = t3.behavior_code1
JOIN subjects                      t4 on t3.subject  = t4.yerkes_code
GROUP BY actor;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks :)

P.S. if this is easier to do in Perl tips also much appreciated

Comment: I haven't bothered to look for other problems, but there is an extra comma before FROM that breaks the statement.

Comment: How is it failing?  Are you getting an error, if so what is it?  Or are you just not getting the columns you expect?  What is the intention of your query?  Also, you don't appear to use t4 but it's joined anyway.

Comment: You probably want `AS anxiety`? Most databases won't be happy to see a string literal where an identifier should be, you shouldn't pick up bad habits from MySQL's laxity. Same goes for using double quotes for string literals instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(IF(...))` doesn't make sense, since it will count the row regardless of what the IF returns. I think you probably want `SUM(IF(...)) as anxiety`.

Also, the syntax of your IF is wrong. It should be:

```
SUM(IF(t2.group1 = "anxiety behavior" AND t3.sex = "M", 1, 0)) AS anxiety
```

or simply:

```
SUM(t2.group1 = "anxiety behavior" AND t3.sex = "M") AS anxiety
```

since conditional expressions return 1 for true, 0 for false.

Answer (score 1):

using count(if(...)), should use null for the false part. replace 0 to null.